# a parameter of a function to access a json key in javascript , node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parameter-passing

I have a json with 10 elements like this:  `{"id":"2","name":"Peter","number":"A4584857","father":"Gerart","color":"green"}`

i try  to modifiy the json so i have a function who read and write like this:

```
function updatefilelocal(id,texto) {
   const fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile('students.json', (err, data) => {  

      if (err) throw err;
      let json = JSON.parse(data); 
      console.log('This is after the read call')

      const filename='students.json';
      var file=json; 
    
      file.alumnos[id].color= texto

      fs.writeFile(filename,JSON.stringify(file),function writeJson(err){
        if (err)return console.log(err);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(file));
        //console.log('writing to'+filename )
    
      });
    });
}
```

so , with this line : `file.alumnos[id].color= texto`  and with this function : `updatefilelocal(2,'yellow')`   i can modify the key color in my json , Well, it works but when i want to modifiy the key 'name' of my element i have to change color for name like this: `file.alumnos[id].name= texto` and it s ok but  what i want to do it s add a third parameter in my function :
 `function updatefilelocal(id,texto,third_parameter) {...}`  to change 'color' on 'name'.  i will call my function like this : `updatefilelocal(id,texto,name)` if i want to change the name of my element or
`updatefilelocal(id,texto,color)` if i want to change the color of my element...i have tried all...i have put brackets `file.alumnos[id].{third parameter}= texto`  but nothing worked...
thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, post your json structure here. Is it an array? Or an object with those key/values ?

Comment: {"alumnos":[ {"id":"1","name":"Peter","number":"A4584837","father":"Gerart","color":"green"},{"id":"2","name":"Maria","number":"A4584857","father":"pett","color":"yellow"},{"id":"3","name":"John","number":"A4584857","father":"Juan","color":"green"},etc...]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in the key as the third parameter, and access it using `[key]`. So an example in your code would be:

```js
function updatefilelocal(id, texto, key) {
  // Your code
  file.alumnos[id][key] = texto;
  // Rest of your code
}
```

and you can choose to change color or name by calling `updatefilelocal` with either `updatefilelocal(id, texto, 'color')` or `updatefilelocal(id, texto, 'name')`.

Here's an example to see how it works:

```js
let x = { a: 1, b: 2 };

function changeKeyValue(obj, key, val) {
  obj[key] = val;
}

changeKeyValue(x, 'a', 3); // x = { a: 3, b: 2 }
changeKeyValue(x, 'b', 4); // x = { a: 3, b: 4 }
```

Comment: So great! i did'nt know this way. Thanks a lot @JY Loh!!